# Failing Redirection and How to Inspect Named Route Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I have a singular resource and a plural controller: PeopleController and resource :person in the routes file.  In my controller create action, I have a redirect_to @person, which is supposed to redirect to the show action for the just-created person object.   In my controller test, I assert that response.should redirect_to(@person).  It seems straightforward to me, but when I run the spec, I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create 
 NoMethodError: 
   undefined method `people_url' for #<PeopleController:0x00000002d7d988>
```

It appears that the redirect in the create action is trying to go to an index action, which doesn't (and shouldn't) exist for a singular resource.

The routing table is simple:

```
              person POST   /person(.:format)              people#create
          new_person GET    /person/new(.:format)          people#new
         edit_person GET    /person/edit(.:format)         people#edit
                     GET    /person(.:format)              people#show
                     PUT    /person(.:format)              people#update
                     DELETE /person(.:format)              people#destroy
```

I understand why I'm getting the undefined method error: there is no people_url for a singular resource, only a person_url.  I'm confused about why the redirect_to @person is trying to invoke people_url to begin with.  Shouldn't it default to using the person_url named route, and pass the id of the newly saved person object? I can get the test to pass by using redirect_to person_path(@person), but why is this different from what redirect_to @person is supposed to return?

What would be the best way to inspect the constructed URLs from the named routes in helper methods?  Besides writing failing tests of course.  That I'm really good at already :-).

Comment: include the definition of `resources :persons` in routes.rb

Comment: Ditto what @prusswan said. Hard to tell what exactly the issue is without seeing how you defined the routes.

Comment: I specifically don't want a plural resource, which is why I don't want to use resources :persons.  The Rails convention is that you use plural controllers no matter whether the underlying resource is singular or plural.  So I have my "People" controller.  But I want the underlying resource to be singular, so I have "resource :person" in the routes.  Using "resources :persons" doesn't solve the problem, and I still don't understand why the redirect_to @person wasn't working.

Comment: so how did you map the resource to a different controller?